# VueJS - Update a parent computed property after a child component modifies prop data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a relatively complex API request object I need to make, with a large number of UI components responsible for updating different properties of the object.

I'm passing the basic request model as a prop from a parent component to its children, which pass it on to theirs (down several "generations").

At the parent level, I have a computed property that returns a field of this data model, and a watch on that computed property.

When a child component updates the property on the model, it successfully updates everywhere that has a reference to it, but the computed property on the parent fails to recalculate, and resultantly the watch never activates.

I'm guessing I've missed the point somewhere along here, but I can't think about how else to update without resorting to long event chains through the UI.. How should I be approaching this instead?

Comment: just passing the prop to the children and uptading there wont tringger the computed recalc, use a `.sync` and update the variable with an $emit (In the child) , then the parent computed prop should recalculate if somethin inside it updates.

Comment: @Woohaik So.. for a component that's 4 layers deep, this would have to bubble an event all the way up to the "owner" of the object for it to update. That was what I wanted to avoid :S The .sync thing seems to only be a feature in Vue2.3? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sounds like you are losing reactivity somewhere in your computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone with a similar question - from my research it seems that modifying reference values on props is not the intended approach for VueJS. Which is a shame, because initially it seemed like quite a neat pattern.

I've implemented vuex now, which is working well, and avoids long lines of events going back to the original owner of the prop data.

IF you wanted to press it, then modifying references on the object itself will force updates down the chain. So (e.g.) if you wanted to update an array property of the prop data, then instead of "pushing" to it, you would replace the whole array object (causing other components with computed properties on that array property to recalculate). But again, not recommended.